# How to insert values result set into hashmap without iterating in Java 1.4?

Tags: java, hashmap, resultset

I want to validate a value against values retrieved from a result set's first column.  I have to do the same validation operation approximately 1000 times.  So, I want to decrease the time complexity of this comparison from  O(n) to constant.  Is there some function through which I can put all of the values of result set's column into a hashmap without iterating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no

Answer (score 2):

(I assume you're talking about a JDBC ResultSet).  No, but that isn't a problem for you.  It took O(n) to generate the ResultSet, so you shouldn't be worried about using O(n) more time to put them in a hashmap, or just do the validation against the whole ResultSet directly.

Comment: ... not to mention that the client-side cost of iterating and building the HashMap is likely to have a much smaller 'constant of proportionality' than the cost of doing the query and transmitting the data.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to do the validation as part of the database query itself (in the where clause) by passing the value from your code to the query ?